# Google Add Script Loop and Array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to loop on every cell on my spreadsheet and look for a certain cell that is not equal to 100. I was able to loop over each cell for each column and row. As a test, I input 5 or 6 cells with different value. I am trying to use Array to get the value and show it to my Log, but every time I did that it always show me 1.0 answer.

**Google App Script:**

```
function countValue() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getValues();
  spreadsheet.forEach(function(row) {
    row.forEach(function(col){
      if (col != 100) {
        var notNumber100 = [];
        var invalidNumber = notNumber100.push(col);
        Logger.log(invalidNumber);
      };
    });
  });
}
```

Below is the log that I get every time I run the script. The invalid value that I put has a length of 5 or 6.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search the cells which has no value of `100` and put the different value to the searched cells. (`As a test, I input 5 or 6 cells with different value.`)

#### Modification points:

- In your script, at `var invalidNumber = notNumber100.push(col);`, `invalidNumber` is the length of the array of `notNumber100`. And, the array of `notNumber100` is redeclared every loop. By this, the array length is always `1`. As the result, you see the value of `1` at the log. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

If you want to check the values of array and the cell coordinates, you can modify as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modification, the active range is used. This is from your script.

```
function countValue() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var startCol = range.getColumn();
  var spreadsheet = range.getValues();
  spreadsheet.forEach(function(row, i) {
    row.forEach(function(col, j){
      if (col != 100) {
        var notNumber100 = [];
        notNumber100.push(col);
        Logger.log("row: %s, col: %s, valueOfnotNumber100: %s", startRow + i, startCol + j, notNumber100);
        // range.offset(i, j, 1, 1).setValue(6); // When you use this line, the cell value is replaced with the value of `6`.
      };
    });
  });
}
```

If you want to search all cells in a sheet, you can also use the following script.

```
function countValue() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange();
  range.getValues().forEach(function(row, i) {
    row.forEach(function(col, j){
      if (col != 100) {
        var notNumber100 = [];
        notNumber100.push(col);
        Logger.log("row: %s, col: %s, valueOfnotNumber100: %s", i + 1, j + 1, notNumber100);
        // range.offset(i, j, 1, 1).setValue(6); // When you use this line, the cell value is replaced with the value of `6`.
      };
    });
  });
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

For example, if you want to search the cells with no value of `100` and replace it with other value, I think that you can also use TextFinder. When TextFinder is used, the sample script is as follows and the process cost can be reduced a little.

```
function countValue() {
  // Search the cells 
  var textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().createTextFinder("^(?!100).+$").useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(true);
  
  // Confirm the cell coordinates and the cell values.
  textFinder.findAll().forEach(r => {
    Logger.log("row: %s, col: %s, cellValue: %s", r.getRow(), r.getColumn(), r.getValue());
  });
  
  // Replace the searched cells with the value of `6`.
  textFinder.replaceAllWith("6");
}
```

- In this case, when `var textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().createTextFinder("^(?!100).+$").useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(true);` is modified to `var textFinder = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().createTextFinder("^(?!100).+$").useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(true);`, all sheets are used as the target sheets.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate your help. It actually works and now my automation is complete. I am just wondering if there is a way that we can also get the Cell ID of the cell which has no value of 100?

Comment: @ian Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `I am just wondering if there is a way that we can also get the Cell ID of the cell which has no value of 100?`, I would like to support you. But I cannot understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand about your new question.

Comment: Let say, the cell that has no value of 100 is C10, so instead of getting the count of the value that has not equal to 100, I want to get the cell ID which is C10.

Comment: @ian Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. I would like to confirm about my understanding of your new question. You want to retrieve the cell coordinate (A1Notation) of the cells that the value is not `100` in a sheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, if that would be possible. FYI, I am watching your tutorial in Skillshare.

Comment: @ian Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that you can use the script of `var res = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().createTextFinder("^(?!100).+$").useRegularExpression(true).matchEntireCell(true).findAll().map(r => r.getA1Notation());`. In this case, you can see the result value with log using `console.log(res)`. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. I just started your tutorial in Skillshare and it gave me more knowledge in Google App Script. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
function countValue() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const shts = ss.getSheets();//get all sheets
  const found = [];//found array
  shts.forEach(sh=>{
    sh.getDataRange().getValues().forEach((r,i) => {
      r.forEach((c,j)=>{
        if(c != 100) {
          found.push({sheet:sh.getName(),row:i+1,col:j+1,value:c});//saving data
        }
      });
    });
  });
  let html = found.map(obj=>{`<br>sheet: ${obj.sheet} row: ${obj.row} col: ${obj.col} value: ${obj.value}`});//creating html for dialog
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Looking at the entire spreadsheet');//display data in dialog
}
```